React Native in Network Request Failed ReactNativeJS ▶︎ [TypeError: Network request failed]
while using fetch in react native for anroid development.Getting Network Error , i am unable to make api request to the server
` fetch("http://keycloak_url/realms/testing/protocol/openid-connect/token", requestOptions)`

it is woring fine above android 12 version devices but while it comming belowthe 12 or 12 it is throwing network request failed error.
i am using
NPM 10.5.1
React-native 0.73.6
java 17
I need a soluting for this error and an explantion will be plus.

It is an https request
